# Getting Latitude Longitude from GoogleMaps in TWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, delphi

I'm passing an address to Google Maps and I'm able to display a map and place a marker in TWebBrowser, but I'm trying to also return the Latitude and Longitude coordinates to my Delphi Win32 app.  What do I need to add?

```
  private
    { Private declarations }
    HTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
    fAddress: String;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string); reintroduce;
  end;

var
  ViewMaps                     : TViewMaps;
  Flags                        : OLEVariant;
  address, MapType             : string;
  Title, Lat, Lng              : AnsiString;

implementation

Uses ShredMain, ActiveX, MaintForm_u, NewSchedule;

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TViewMaps.create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string);
begin
  inherited create(AOwner);
  fAddress := AAddress; // fAddress is now stored to form variable
end;

const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
//'<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />'+
'<input type="hidden" id="lat" value="" />'+
'<input type="hidden" id="lng" value="" />'+
''+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22"></script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
'  var trafficLayer;'+
'  var bikeLayer;'+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 11, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();'+
'    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();'+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          PutMarker(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","+results[0].geometry.location.lng());'+
'          document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat;'+
'          document.getElementById("lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng;'+
'        } else {'+
'          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function TrafficOn()   { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function TrafficOff()  { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }'+
''+''+
'  function BicyclingOn() { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function BicyclingOff(){ bikeLayer.setMap(null);}'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOn() { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }'+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';

procedure TViewMaps.OnShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
  HtmlElement: IHtmlElement;
  sLat, sLng: string;

begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  MemoAddress.Lines.Text := NewServiceForm.MapAddress;
  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
      aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
      aStream.Free;
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;

  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do // wait for google
  begin
    sleep(0);
    application.processmessages;
  end;
  // 05/11/2016 - Show the address on the map
  fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(fAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);

  HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(fAddress)]), 'JavaScript');

  HtmlElement := (WebBrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lat');
  sLat  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
  HtmlElement := (WebBrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lng');
  sLng  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);

  LatitudeEdit.Text := sLat;
  LongitudeEdit.Text := sLng;

end;
```

I have Lat and Lng defined as AnsiString, but sLat and sLng are defined as String locally in my OnShow event.  My two Tedit boxes for Longitude and Latitude are blank. Am I passing the wrong variable to them?

Comment: @John Easley - To get it working, I had to add () at the end of geometry.location.lat, but I only get the results when I add a message line like ShowMessage('Hello') after the HtmlElement := in my OnShow event.  Otherwise the results are empty.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the coordinates available within your Delphi code, you need to store the values in the html (DOM), then extract them from your Delphi code. To start, you can create hidden fields to store the javascript values in your HTML between Body tag:

```
  <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" id="lng" value="0" />
```

Then in your javascript function, set the hidden values:

```
document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
document.getElementById("lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```

Then to obtain the values in your Delphi application, use something like:

```
var
  lat, lng: string;
  HtmlElement: IHtmlElement;
begin
  HtmlElement := (Webbrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lat');
  lat  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
  HtmlElement := (Webbrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lng');
  lng  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
end;
```

Here I've rewritten your entire unit. Please take special notice to the changes to your HTMLStr constant, especially the codeAddress function, which uses a marker to obtain the lat/lng values.

```
unit fmViewMaps;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,OleCtrls, MSHTML, SHDocVw, StdCtrls;

type

  TLocation = Record
    Lat: String;
    Lng: String;
    Result: string;
  end;

  TFrmViewMaps = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    LatitudeEdit: TEdit;
    LongitudeEdit: TEdit;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fAddress: string;
    HTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
    procedure LoadGoogleApi;
    function GoogleApiReady: boolean;
    procedure ExecuteScript(AScript: string);
    function GetElementByID(AElementID: string): IHTMLElement;
    function GetElementValue(ElementID: string): string;
    function GetGeocode(Address: string): TLocation;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string); reintroduce;
  end;

var
  FrmViewMaps: TFrmViewMaps;

implementation

uses  ActiveX;

{$R *.dfm}

const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
''+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?  v=3.22"></script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
'  var trafficLayer;'+
'  var bikeLayer;'+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 11, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();'+
'    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();'+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()); '+
'          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ '+
'            position: myLatlng, '+
'            title: "", '+
'            map: map '+
'          }); '+
'        markersArray.push(marker); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = myLatlng.lat(); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = myLatlng.lng(); '+
' '+
'        } else {'+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = "error"; '+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = "error"; '+
'           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +    status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function TrafficOn()   { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function TrafficOff()  { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }'+
''+''+
'  function BicyclingOn() { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function BicyclingOff(){ bikeLayer.setMap(null);}'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOn() { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }'+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'<input type="hidden" id="hiddenlat" value="0" />'+
'<input type="hidden" id="hiddenlng" value="0" />'+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';


constructor TFrmViewMaps.create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string);
begin
  inherited create(AOwner);
  fAddress := AAddress;
end;

procedure TFrmViewMaps.LoadGoogleApi;
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank'); //Set the location to an empty page

  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create; //create a TStream to load the Page from the string   
    try
      aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
      aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
      aStream.Free;
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;

  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do // wait for google
  begin
    sleep(0);
    application.processmessages;
  end;

end;

function TFrmViewMaps.GoogleApiReady: boolean;
begin
  result := (HTMLWindow2 <> nil);
end;

procedure TFrmViewMaps.ExecuteScript(AScript: string);
begin
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(AScript, 'JavaScript');
end;

function TFrmViewMaps.GetElementByID(AElementID: string): IHTMLElement;
begin
  result := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementByID(AElementID);
end;

function TFrmViewMaps.GetElementValue(ElementID: string): string;
var
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
begin
  HtmlElement := GetElementByID(ElementID);
  result := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
end;

procedure RemoveInvalidGeoLookupChars(var AString: string);
begin
  AString := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(AString), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  // remove invalid chars
  AString := StringReplace(AString, #39, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);  // single quotes
  AString := StringReplace(AString, #34, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);  // double quotes
end;

function TFrmViewMaps.GetGeocode(Address: string): TLocation;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result.Lat := '0';
  result.Lng := '0';
  LatitudeEdit.text := '0';
  LongitudeEdit.text := '0';
  result.Result := 'OK';
  application.processmessages;
  RemoveInvalidGeoLookupChars(address);
  application.processmessages;
  ExecuteScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(address)]));

  while (GetElementValue('hiddenlat') = '0') do
    application.processmessages;

  result.Lat := GetElementValue('hiddenlat');
  result.lng := GetElementValue('hiddenlng');
end;

procedure TFrmViewMaps.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Location: TLocation;
begin
  LoadGoogleApi;
  Location := GetGeoCode(fAddress);
  LatitudeEdit.Text := Location.Lat;
  LongitudeEdit.Text := Location.Lng;
end;

end.
```

To geocode an address from another form, use the following syntax:

```
frmViewMaps:= TFrmViewMaps.create(self, 'One Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052');
try
  frmViewMaps.showmodal;
finally
  frmViewMaps.destroy;
end;
```

Comment: I added what you suggested, but I changed `getElementByID` to `getElementById`, and `document.getElementByID("Lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng;` to `document.getElementByID("Lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng;`. 

Rather than returning the Lat and Lng values, it's giving me "function(){return a}" for Lat, and "function(){return b}" for Lng.

Comment: Sorry, DOM node ids are case sensitive in most browsers. Change all lat/lng ids to lower case.."lat", "lng"

Comment: Same results returning "function(){return a}"... Here's where I added to HTML:
`constructor TViewMaps.create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string);
begin
  inherited create(AOwner);
  fAddress := AAddress; // fAddress is now stored to form variable
end;

const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
'<input type="hidden" id="lat" value="" />'+
'<input type="hidden" id="lng" value="" />'+
''+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22"></script> '+`

Comment: Here's part of my Javascript in function codeAddress:
`...
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          PutMarker(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","+results[0].geometry.location.lng());'+
'          document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat;'+
'          document.getElementById("lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng;'+
'        } else...`

Comment: Here's part of my Delphi code:
`fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(fAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(fAddress)]), 'JavaScript');
  HtmlElement := (WebBrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lat');
  lat  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
  HtmlElement := (WebBrowser1.document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('lng');
  lng  := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
  LatitudeEdit.Text := lat;
  LongitudeEdit.Text := lng;`

Comment: please update your question with your code changes.. and refrain from posting code blocks in comments ..thank you

Comment: Will do, sorry about that... still trying to learn this system.

Comment: No worries... Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer with a rewrite of your code. I've tested, and it works.

Comment: My code only populates the two edit boxes on the OnShow event if I add a message line like ShowMessage('Hello') after the HtmlElement := line.  It appears that the ShowMessage is either creating a delay, or changes the focus somehow.  Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry I missed the rewrite. I'll compile and test.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon.  I have a simple button that when clicked is suppose to clear the marker(s).  When I click it nothing happens.  The Delphi code when clicked is just `HTMLWindow2.execScript('ClearMarkers()', 'JavaScript');`.  Should I add anything else?

Comment: It looks like the marker isn't being added to the markers array.. I will have to update the code..

Comment: editing code.. look at the codeAddress function.  I added the new marker to the markers array by  "markersArray.push(marker);"

Comment: I was trying to find a way to evaluate the markersArray to see what was there, but now it works great!  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can return the LatLng objects from your marker by using `google.maps.Marker#getPosition`.

You can then retrieve the coordinates from the `google.maps.LatLng` objects using `LatLng#lat` and `LatLng#lng`.