# Posting wrong record information to table

Tags: delphi

While looping through my customer table and posting latitude and longitude values based on an address, the first set of lat/lng values are posting to records number 1 and 2, and then subsequently every record thereafter is off by one.  When I step through in Debug mode I see that the values for the first record are still there on my second iteration. After that, it corrects itself, but every records values are for the address or record above it. Why?

Here's my code:

```
procedure TViewMaps.StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iRecs, i : Integer;
  Location : TLocation;
begin
  ViewMaps := TViewMaps.create(self, MapAddress);
  Customer.Open;
  iRecs:= Customer.RecordCount;
  i := 0;
  While Not Customer.EOF do
    begin
      i := i + 1;
      Customer.Edit;
      MapAddress := CustomerSAddress1.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress2.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress3.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress4.AsString + ', ' + CustomerSCity.AsString + ', ' + CustomerSState.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSZip.AsString;

      fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(MapAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
      Location := GetGeoCode(fAddress);

      Customerlat.AsString := Location.Lat;
      Customerlng.AsString := Location.Lng;

      StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Update Geocode for address ' + ' [Count ' + IntToStr(i) + ' of ' + IntToStr(iRecs) + ']';
      Sleep(3000);
      StatusBar1.Refresh;
      Customer.Next;
    end;
end;
```

Okay, I modified the code based on your suggestion (not sure I'm doing it the right way), but I'm getting the exact same result.  This program is just a run once application to populate the lat/lng values to our database, and the delay is because I was running into a Google query limit and the app was posting to the database before the results were back from Google, so I had to slow it down.

Here's the updated code:

```
procedure TViewMaps.StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Customer.Open;
  iRecCount:= Customer.RecordCount;
  iCurRec := 0;
  Customer.First;
  if Not Customer.EOF then Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TViewMaps.OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  iCurRec := iCurRec + 1;
  //ShowMessage('I am here and iCurRec = ' + inttostr(iCurRec));
  Customer.Edit;
  // Load full customer address into MapAddress
  MapAddress := CustomerSAddress1.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress2.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress3.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSAddress4.AsString + ', ' + CustomerSCity.AsString + ', ' + CustomerSState.AsString + ' ' + CustomerSZip.AsString;
  fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(MapAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  // Get Longitude and Latitude from Google Maps
  Location := GetGeoCode(fAddress);
  // Populate lat and lng fields in Customer table
  Customerlat.AsString := Location.Lat;
  Customerlng.AsString := Location.Lng;
  // Post record to Customer table
  Customer.Post;
  StatusBar1.SimpleText:= 'Update Geocode for address ' + ' [Count ' + IntToStr(iCurRec) + ' of ' + IntToStr(iRecCount) + ']';
  StatusBar1.Refresh;
  // Grab the next record in the Customer table
  Customer.Next;
  if Customer.EOF then Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Ok... here's the codeAddress javascript

```
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()); '+
'          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ '+
'            position: myLatlng, '+
'            title: "", '+
'            map: map '+
'          }); '+
'        markersArray.push(marker); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = myLatlng.lat(); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = myLatlng.lng(); '+
' '+
'        } else {'+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = "error"; '+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = "error"; '+
'           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +    status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
```

And here's the Delphi code:

```
constructor TViewMaps.create(AOwner: TComponent; AAddress: string);
begin
  inherited create(AOwner);
  fAddress := AAddress; // fAddress is now stored to form variable
end;

procedure TViewMaps.LoadGoogleApi;
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank'); //Set the location to an empty page
  MemoAddress.Lines.Text := '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043';
  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    aStream := TMemoryStream.Create; //create a TStream to load the Page from the string
    try
      aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
      aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
    finally
      aStream.Free;
    end;
    HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
  end;

  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do // wait for google
  begin
    sleep(0);
    application.processmessages;
  end;
end;

function TViewMaps.GoogleApiReady: boolean;
begin
  result := (HTMLWindow2 <> nil);
end;

procedure TViewMaps.ExecuteScript(AScript: string);
begin
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(AScript, 'JavaScript');
end;

function TViewMaps.GetElementByID(AElementID: string): IHTMLElement;
begin
  result := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementByID(AElementID);
end;

function TViewMaps.GetElementValue(ElementID: string): string;
var
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
begin
  HtmlElement := GetElementByID(ElementID);
  result := HtmlElement.getAttribute('value', 0);
end;

procedure RemoveInvalidGeoLookupChars(var AString: string);
begin
  AString := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(AString), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  // remove invalid chars
  AString := StringReplace(AString, #39, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);  // single quotes
  AString := StringReplace(AString, #34, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);  // double quotes
end;

procedure TViewMaps.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Location: TLocation;
begin
  MapAddress := '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway' + ', ' + 'Mountain View' + ', ' + 'CA' + ' ' + '94043';
  ViewMaps := TViewMaps.create(self, MapAddress);
  LoadGoogleApi;
  address := MemoAddress.Lines.Text;
  fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(address), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Location := GetGeoCode(fAddress);
  LatitudeEdit.Text := Location.Lat;
  LongitudeEdit.Text := Location.Lng;
end;

function TViewMaps.GetGeocode(Address: string): TLocation;
begin
  result.Lat := '0';
  result.Lng := '0';
  LatitudeEdit.text := '0';
  LongitudeEdit.text := '0';
  result.Result := 'OK';
  application.processmessages;
  RemoveInvalidGeoLookupChars(address);
  application.processmessages;
  ExecuteScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(Address)]));

  while (GetElementValue('hiddenlat') = '0') do
    application.processmessages;

  result.Lat := GetElementValue('hiddenlat');
  result.Lng := GetElementValue('hiddenlng');
end;

procedure TViewMaps.StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iRecCount, iCurRec: integer;
  Location: TLocation;
  fAddress, MapAddress: string;
begin
    Customer.open;
    Customer.first;
    iRecCount := Customer.RecordCount;
    iCurRec := 0;
    while not Customer.eof do
    begin
      inc(iCurRec);
      fillchar(Location, sizeof(Location), 0);
      MapAddress := CustomerSAddress1.asstring+' '+CustomerSAddress2.asstring+' '+CustomerSCity.asstring+', '+CustomerSState.asstring+' '+CustomerSZip.asstring;
      fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(MapAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
      fillchar(Location, sizeof(Location), 0);
      Location := GetGeocode(fAddress);
      if (Location.lat <> 'error') and (Location.lat <> '0') then
      begin
        Customer.edit;
        CustomerLat.AsString := Location.Lat;
        CustomerLng.AsString := Location.Lng;
        Customer.Post;
      end;
      Statusbar1.SimpleText := 'Update Geocode for address ' + ' [Count ' + IntToStr(iCurRec) + ' of ' + IntToStr(iRecCount) + ']';
      application.processmessages;
      sleep(2000); // adjust to not exceed Google API query limit
      Customer.next;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think this will necessarily solve your problem, but you should explicitly call Customer.Post immediately after setting Customerlng.AsString.  The change would get posted during the call to Customer.Next, but it is bad practice to rely on this.  And as for calling Sleep in your loop ... well.

Comment: @MartynA - I tried the Customer.Post as well as a Customer.Prior after when I hit the second record, but no luck.  The first and second record still get duplicated result values for lat/lng and every record there after is off by one.

Comment: Sorry, there's no polite way to say this: that loop is horrific - try one of the alternatives I've suggested in my answer.  At the very least, they should allow any remaining problem to be debugged more easily.

Comment: A three-second delay between records? I hope you only have a handful of customers; if more, your users are going to hate your slow-moving app. I read your code and threw up a little in the back of my mouth, and I don't have to use your app.

Comment: Please clarify the comment "When I step through in Debug mode I see that the values for the first record are still there on my second iteration".  Which values specifically are you referring to?  The values from the Customer* fields from the data set?  Or is the value returned from GetGeoCode the same, even though different addresses were used both times?

Comment: Re your edit, see updates #1 and #2 to my answer.  #2 in particular should help you identify whether it is the delay you are introducing to avoid calling GetGeoLocation too frequently which is actually causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of SO should know that this is a continuation to one of OP's previous questions - [Getting Latitude Longitude from GoogleMaps in TWebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216778/getting-latitude-longitude-from-googlemaps-in-twebbrowser/37217745?noredirect=1#comment62306816_37217745)

I created a test using the code below. My customer table field names are different, but you'll get the idea.

Notice to keep the time between Customer.edit and Customer.post as narrow as possible, to avoid any premature posts.  Also, make sure that Customer table doesn't have any events that would cause an interruption during your loop.  Only edit/post if a valid geocode has been returned.  And for good measure, the Location record is initialized at each iteration.

```
procedure TForm2.StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iRecCount,
  iCurRec: integer;
  Location: TLocation;
  fAddress, MapAddress: string;
begin
    Customer.open;
    Customer.first;
    iRecCount := Customer.RecordCount;
    iCurRec := 0;
    while not Customer.eof do
    begin
      inc(iCurRec);
      fillchar(Location, sizeof(Location), 0);
      MapAddress := CustomerAddress.asstring+' '+CustomerAddress2.asstring+' '+CustomerCity.asstring+', '+CustomerState.asstring+' '+CustomerZip.asstring;
      fAddress := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(MapAddress), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
      fillchar(Location, sizeof(Location), 0);
      Location := form1.GetGeocode(fAddress);
      if (Location.lat <> 'error') and (Location.lat <> '0') then
      begin
        Customer.edit;
        CustomerLatitude.AsString := Location.Lat;
        CustomerLongitude.AsString := Location.Lng;
        Customer.Post;
      end;
      Statusbar1.SimpleText := 'Update Geocode for address ' + ' [Count ' + IntToStr(iCurRec) + ' of ' + IntToStr(iRecCount) + ']';
      application.processmessages;
      sleep(1000); // adjust to not exceed Google API query limit
      Customer.next;
    end;
end;
```

Also, modify your codeAddress Javascript function to clear the hidden page values.

```
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = "0"; '+
'    document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = "0"; '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()); '+
'          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ '+
'            position: myLatlng, '+
'            title: "", '+
'            map: map '+
'          }); '+
'        markersArray.push(marker); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = myLatlng.lat(); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = myLatlng.lng(); '+
' '+
'        } else {'+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = "error"; '+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = "error"; '+
'           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +    status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
```

Comment: I have this all on one form, so I removed the reference to form1.  I'm still having the same problem though, which is the previous lat/lng values being returned from the GetGeocode function call.  I've checked during debugging an I'm passing the correct fAddress to the GetGeocode function, but upon return the "Location" variable contains the previous lat/lng values.

Comment: Did you make any code changes to your geocode function?  I'm not able to reproduce your issue...

Comment: @Hackbrew Do you check the status code in the response? Would it be possible for you to publish the, say, three first addresses you are asking for?

Comment: @John Easley - I've added the javascript and the Delphi code above.

Comment: @Hackbrew what database are you using?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg - The responses always shows OK.  The first address is 8045 Frankford Ave, Philadelphia, PA 19136, the second one is 6613 Frankford Ave, Philadelphia, PA 19135, and the third one is 9850 Bustleton Ave, Philadelphia, PA 19115.

Comment: @Hackbrew  the geocode function returns a valid geocode, or 'error', which we check for..

Comment: @Hackbrew the first two are on the same street, you should test with addresses further way from each other...

Comment: @John Easley - It's something that was passed over to me called BDE - Paradox 7.  I'd like to migrate out of it because from what I've read it's very outdated.  There's not that many records in the database, and the users aren't adding that many (maybe 30 records per day).

Comment: @John Easley - I tried addresses that are on opposite sides of the country, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I edited your question's CodeAddress function to initialize the hidden page vars.. see if that helps..

Comment: @John Easley - I'm sorry, I don't see the change.  The JavaScript codeAddress function looks the same, correct?

Comment: @John Easley - That worked like a charm until I hit a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Hackbrew it's a good idea to geocode on demand versus trying to do all customers at once, that way you avoid the query limit issue altogether.. Is my answer okay?

Comment: @John Easley - Yes, I awarded you the answer.  My goal is to first get the customer list populated with Lat/Lng.  Then when a new customer calls and provides their address, geocode that new address on demand, and also run some javascript to determine proximity to other future pending jobs to create efficiency.  I'm sure I'll have another question when I get to that point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where in your loop you are making these observations, but in the code that was originally in your q, the changes to the current record will not get posted until your call to Customer.Next which will post any changes before moving the table cursor to the next record.  But you should not rely on this behaviour, especially as you are only calling Customer.Next after a delay.

Try this instead:

```
  Customerlng.AsString := Location.Lng;
  Customer.Post;
```

I would not be at all surprised if it turns out that the problem you're having turns out to be caused by some artefact of the delay you say you're having to introduce to avoid calling GetGeoLocation too frequently.   A way to eliminate that as the cause is to use a test version of your original loop with no delay (Sleep()) in it whatsoever and a replacement `GetGeoCode` routine which simply returns some unique values each time it is called.  This replacement `GetGeoCode` routine could simply increment the `Lat` and `Lng` members of a record each time it is called and return the updated record.

This simplified test version should work correctly.  If it doesn't, your code must be doing something you are not telling us about and only you can debug it.  If on the other hand it *does* work correctly, you need to come up with a better way of avoiding calling the real `GetGeoCode` too frequently.  In particular it should not

a) call Sleep() in your app's main gui thread, which is what you were doing in the original version of your q; and

b) attempt to execute entirely within an OnClick handler.

If you really must introduce a delay, do something like

- Add a TTimer to your form with a delay of 3000 or whatever.
- In your StartBtnClick, simply call Customer.First, check for Customer.Eof and if it's false, activate the tttimer.  Then exit.
- In its OnTimer, update the current Customer record, call Customer.Post, do your status bar refresh, call Customer.Next, check for Customer.Eof and cancel the ttimer if Eof is true so that its OnTimer won't be called again.

You should protect your OnTimer against re-entrancy (i.e. OnTimer being called again before it has finished executing).  Have a boolean flag `UpdateExecuting` on your form, test for it being true on entry to OnTimer and exit immediately if it is, otherwise set it to true, then set it to false in the `finally` section of a `try`..`finally` in the remainder of your OnTimer.  Or, you could disable the TTimer on entry to its OnTimer event and re-enable it in a `finally` section.

If you prefer not to use a TTimer, you could do what I've suggested for its OnTimer in an Application.OnIdle handler.

Best of all would be to do the updates in a background thread, but how easy it would be to retrieve the updates into the Customer instance in your gui thread depends on what kind of TDataSet your Customer table is.

Btw: your Customer table isn't using an index that includes Customerlat or Customerlng **is it**?

Also btw: your q doesn't contain a proper MCVE, which is what a question of this type should contain, because without one, there is no way for readers to reproduce the problem.  Without one, I think it is likely to attract votes to close.

Comment: Protecting against timer reentrancy could also be accomplished by disabling the timer upon entry and enabling when finished.

Comment: @LURD:  Sure, and the OP will presumably take note, thanks.  Personally, I always tend to use an explicit flag, as the "state" involved my need to be taken into account in other code.