# Javascript calling Google Maps not working in Delphi app

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps-api-3

The is a continuation of an issue I had earlier [Posting wrong record information to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621605/posting-wrong-record-information-to-table) in the same application. When I add the Javascript below I get a script error. I'm guessing I'm not returning the value properly with the GrabDistSWFObject line.

```
const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
''+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?  v=3.24"></script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
'  var trafficLayer;'+
'  var bikeLayer;'+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
'  var GrabDistSWFObject;'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 11, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();'+
'    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();'+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()); '+
'          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ '+
'            position: myLatlng, '+
'            title: "", '+
'            map: map '+
'          }); '+
'        markersArray.push(marker); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = myLatlng.lat(); '+
'        document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = myLatlng.lng(); '+
' '+
'        } else {'+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlat").value = "error"; '+
'            document.getElementById("hiddenlng").value = "error"; '+
'           alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +    status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
''+
'  function GrabDist() {  '+
'         alert("I reached GrabDist");   '+
'   } '+
''+
''+
'  function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {   '+
'         alert("I reached distance");                     '+
'     var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;                  '+
'     var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;                  '+
'   var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180;                  '+
'   var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180;                  '+
'     var theta = lon1-lon2;                             '+
'     var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;                '+
'     var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);    '+
'     dist = Math.acos(dist);                            '+
'     dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;                         '+
'     dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;                         '+
'     if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 };         '+
'     if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 };           '+
'     return GrabDist().set("dist", dist);               '+
'}                                                     '+
''+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function TrafficOn()   { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function TrafficOff()  { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }'+
''+''+
'  function BicyclingOn() { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function BicyclingOff(){ bikeLayer.setMap(null);}'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOn() { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }'+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'<input type="hidden" id="hiddenlat" value="0" />'+
'<input type="hidden" id="hiddenlng" value="0" />'+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';
```

Here's my code calling the Javascript:

```
  sLat := POE_Data.CustomerSLat.Asstring;
  sLng := POE_Data.CustomerSLng.Asstring;
  Lat1 := POE_Data.WOInTempSLat.AsString;
  Lng1 := POE_Data.WOInTempSLng.AsString;
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('distance(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', [sLat, sLng, Lat1, Lng1, '"N"']), 'JavaScript');
```

Here's the script error showing the syntax error.
[image]

Comment: " I get a script error"  Well, what error do you get?  And what is your q?

Comment: I'm getting a Syntax error and my question is why, or what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Yes, but readers cannot see your screen.  Where exactly do you get the error and what does the error message say?

Comment: first error is N is undefined, wrap with double quotes.  Next error after that is caused by GrabDist().set("dist", dist).  Can you post the html that includes the definition of the GrabDistSWFObject?  Always makes sure to post all relevant code..

Comment: @MartynA - I've added the script error for you to view.

Comment: @John Easley - I wrapped the N in double quotes.  There isn't any HTML that defines the GrabDistSWFObject, which I gather could be the problem.  I'll edit the question and repost the complete Javascript.

Comment: If the message refers to the first block of code in your q, its line 1 prior to your edit seems to be blank so has no "Char: 1",  The final line of the block is missing a closing single-quote after the **}**.

Comment: @John Easley - I tried declaring the GrabDistSWFObject as a var, but I still get the script error.  My goal is to return the distance in miles between the two longitude/latitude points.

Comment: @Hackbrew do you want the distance returned to your Delphi app?  There's no indication of that.. also, you could do this entire function in Delphi, why did you choose to do it in Javascript?

Comment: @John Easley - Yes, I would like the distance returned to my Delphi app.  I would prefer to do it in Delphi, but I'm not sure how to call the Google Services without using Javascript.

Comment: @Hackbrew  the function distance seems to always return 0.  I will have to help you rewrite the function over the weekend.. sorry..

Comment: @John Easley - No worries. Thanks and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function GrabDist and function call aren't correctly coded, and probably not needed. Instead, save the returned value to hidden field as follows.

In order to pass the javascript distance result back to your delphi application, add a hidden field to your html page between the body tags - this is where the function will store the result:

```
'<input type="hidden" id="hiddendistance" value="0" />'+
```

Next, I've modified your javascript routine. Delphi seems to have a problem with javascript comments if the comments are on the end of a code line, so omit the comments:

```
' function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) '+
' { '+
'  var R = 6371;  '+
'  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  '+
'  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); '+
'  var a = '+
'    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + '+
'    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * '+
'    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); '+
''+
'  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); '+
'  var d = R * c;  '+
'  if (unit=="N") d /= 1.60934; '+
'  document.getElementById("hiddendistance").value = d; '+
'  return d; '+
'} '+
''+
' function deg2rad(deg) { '+
'  return deg * (Math.PI/180) '+
' } '+
```

And lastly, your delphi code should be similar to:

```
procedure TForm1.ExecuteScript(AScript: string);
begin
  HTMLWindow2.execScript(AScript, 'JavaScript');
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestDistanceClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  lat1 = '47.6740243';
  lng1 = '-122.1220361';
  Lat2 = '34.0691975';
  Lng2 = '-117.2141603';
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Format('distance(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', [lat1, lng1, Lat2, Lng2, '"N"']);
  ExecuteScript(s);
  showmessage('Distance: '+GetElementValue('hiddendistance'));
end;
```

Comment: When I plugged in my variables I got the same exact javascript syntax error.  But when I used your const it worked great. So I'm guessing that I have my variables typed cast wrong.  Thanks!